# Control music of other apps within my app

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currenty trying to find out if it's possible to control the music of other apps, e.g. Spotify, within my app. The two solutions I found are:

- using the SDK of the specific service (e.g. Spotify SDK)
- take over the audio session in my app, but this only allows me to stop/ play the music

I'm trying to find a solution that provides me with pause, play, forward, backward control and access to the title, maybe also the cover. Then I came across the "Sony Headphones Connect" app. It has a page with media control buttons, the title of the current song and is does not require any kind of sing in to Spotify or something else.

[image]

Picture is from the app from the App Store, I tested the controls and they work.

So somehow it must be possible, does anyone have an idea how I can achieve my desired result or how the "Sony Headphones Connect" app is handling this issue?

Comment: Have you tried e.g. the https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller ?

Comment: Yes, but this solution only gives me access to music within my app or the apple music app, not any other app in the App Store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer, the "Sony Headphones Connect" app is controlling the music over bluetooth. So it's not directly possible to control the music of another app.